# How to make a git patch for specific folders

Tags: git

Ok, I have a two commit now

00001 test commit

- foo/test.c
- goo/test.c
- hoo/test.c

00002 test commit2

- goo/test.c

If I used "git format-patch" in this situation, I could get two patch files including all directory(foo,goo,hoo).

0001-test-commit.patch (foo,goo,hoo)

0002-test-commit2.patch (goo)

My question is how to get patches only have "foo" or "hoo" directory parts?

Eg.

0001-test-commit.patch (has foo and hoo only)

0002-test-commit2.patch -> not generated

I couldnt find any matched options...

Comment: Note that `format-patch` is rarely what is wanted. It is simpler to `git diff` directed into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git format-patch --root -- foo hoo
```

`--root` is required to force `format-patch` to consider the first commit.